# macos qemu tap can't ping bridge ip address?

Tags: networking, mac-osx, bridge, qemu

I want to install qemu on macos and use a tap device in the vm.
Below is my step.

1. install qemu

   `brew install qemu`
2. install tuntap, after installation, I can see tap devices in /dev/tapX

   `brew install tuntap`
3. create a bridge

   `sudo ifconfig bridge0 create`
4. configure ip address on bridge0

   `sudo ifconfig bridge0 192.168.122.1/24`
5. `sudo ifconfig bridge0 up`
6. start my qemu vm (which is centos), and log in to the vm, mannually configure the static ip address as 192.168.122.101/24, gateway is 192.168.122.1.

   `sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -vga virtio -show-cursor -usb -device usb-tablet -drive file=centos-temp.qcow2,if=virtio -accel hvf -cpu host -net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no`
7. after the vm starts, I can see a tap0 in the output of ifconfig, and I add tap0 to bridge0

   `sudo ifconfig bridge0 addm tap0`

however, after theses steps, I can't ping 192.168.122.1 in my vm, and neither ping 192.168.122.101 in my mac host.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this as well. Try the macports version of qemu instead of the one from homebrew. It includes a patch needed to get tap working properly.